# Unable to dynamically create directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I am trying to do is load a directive at runtime and then register it for use. I am experimenting within plunker to get the stripped down version working but I cannot seem to do so. In order to compile the directive at runtime you need a reference to the `$compileProvider` and then declare your directive on it. I am storing a string within an element and then evaluating its contents when a button is clicked. The directive does nothing more than `alert('hello')`.

[Plunker for clarity](https://plnkr.co/edit/9L30GSnSqwQn9mQrlMNo?p=catalogue)

Basically I grab the `$compileProvider` reference in the configuration and then eval() a string that declares a directive.

```
var provider;

angular.module('myApp',[]).config(function(['$compileProvider',function($compileProvider){

provider = $compileProvider;

}]));

//will be loaded from server at runtime
//this is a whole string
var directive = '

provider.directive('log',function(){

return {

  link : function()

  {
    alert('hello');

  }

}

});

';


eval(directive);
```

Comment: Suggest you look here: http://www.learn-angularjs-apps-projects.com/AngularJs/dynamically-add-directives-in-angularjs

Comment: 'add the directive at runtime' != 'compile the directive at runtime'. Also, you're running into race condition. `eval(directive)` (which is evil, you probably know this) is executed before `provider = $compileProvider`. That's why executing Angular-related code outside of Angular is always a bad idea.